# Moving files from a server to another with powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

Helo there, 
I have tried to create a script to move a file from a server (defined path) to another server (defined path). I can make it work on the same server/machine, but I am not sure how can I create this so it works from one server to another. 
`get-childitem -Path "Path\A" -Recurse |`
`move-item -destination "Path\B"`

Is there a way where I can simply add the ip of the server from Path A and another Ip to Path B ?

Comment: As long as you have permissions to do so, you can use the UNC paths for both servers like: `\\ServerName\Share\RestOfPath` or `\\IPAddress\Share\RestOfPath`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work provided you have permissions:

```bsh
Move-Item "\\server1\C$\sourceFolder\file.txt" "\\server2\C$\destinationFolder\"
```

UNC paths use a `$` instead of `:` after the drive letter.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I have managed too, I also have another issue. i will post here.

Comment: ForEach-Object ( in $server2 ) {
 rename-item -Path "C:\Users\nicolae.calimanu\Documents\A\"  -newname ($datetime + ".csv")

 }

Trying to rename each file in that path child item of that folder, into a format of name + date time.csv 
I keep renaming only the folder, not the child items...how can I do this?

Comment: gci \\server2\folder\ -File | ForEach-Object { Rename-Item $_ -NewName "somenewname.csv" }